# Problem with retrieving data from an API source and forming drop-down list using js

Tags: javascript, html, api, drop-down-menu

I am trying to understand this `Promise/fetch` thing in js.

```
'use strict'
  const list = document.querySelector('.list');
    function test() {
      return fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/films/', {
        method: 'GET'
      });
    }      
    list.addEventListener('click', event => {
      console.log('TEST');
      alert("TEST");
     });
     test()
     .then( function(response) {
       return response.json();  
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        data.results.forEach(function(episode) {
        const ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.innerHTML = episode.title;
        list.append(ul); 
       })
     })
```

```
.list {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

`<ul class="list"></ul>`

I need to from a `drop-down` list, from all the STAR WARS episodes(done), and more of that (the part where the troubles start) by `click` on the episode it must `return` a list of ships, used in the episode.

As you can see from the link code above - I was able to return the list of episodes correctly, but I just don't know how to create the drop-down menu currently I'm out of ideas, should I make a `ul-li` list, where `ul` - episodes and `ul` - ships?

Kinda hard for me to figure this one out, please Obi-van, you are my last hope.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly what you've done is not a dropdown but a regular list. Use `<select>` tag.

```
  <select id="episodes" class="list"></select>
```

Then just add another element into the markup:

```
  <select id="ships" class="list"></select>
```

Then go to your api documentation and check what it can offer. Firstly let's see what you receive from your endpoint `/films/`: https://swapi.dev/documentation#films
Obviously here you can find titles of each episode. Done by you. But you can also notice that the response has a list of links to starships endpoint. That's what you need for your second list.

1. Getting ships:
   There're plenty of ways but let's take the easiest one. Luckily your api offers you a way to search an episode by title (https://swapi.dev/documentation#search).
   let's build request url:

```
const nameOfEpisode = event.target.value;
const requestUrl = "https://swapi.dev/api/films/?search=${nameOfEpisode}";
```

2. Now we need a click handler. But before implementing it let's to refactor your test() function by giving it a proper name and making it more general so you could reuse it for both requests:

```
function apiGetRequest(url) {
  return fetch(url, method: 'GET').then(response => response.json())
}
```

3. Now click handler:

```
function requestShips(event) {
  const nameOfEpisode = event.target.value;
  const requestUrl = `https://swapi.dev/api/films/?search=${nameOfEpisode}`;
  apiGetRequest(requestUrl).then(data => {
    const { starshipsUrls } = data[0];
    return starshipsUrls;
   }).then(requestStartshipNames)
   .then(renderStartshipList);
 }
```

4. Implementing `requestStartshipNames` will involve several requests (one request per each starshipUrl). To get all the data synchronously let's use `Promise.all`:

```
function requestStartshipNames(starshipUrls){
  return Promise.all(starshipUrls.map(url => apiGetRequest(url)));
}
```

5. Now to render the starships list you'll need to implement `renderStartshipList` function:

```
function renderStartshipList(starships){
  const startShipsList = document.querySelector('#ships');
  const starcheepsNames = starships.map(({ name }) => {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerHTML = name;
    startShipsList.append(option); 
 })            
}
```

Of course you'll need to refactor your own code in order to match it with the new `apiGetRequest` utility function, new click handler and the new markup.

Good luck!

Comment: Thx a lot! And if I want to build a regular list with ships-of-the-episode click event I should just avoid first part with the select tag and stick to your plan and refactor my code, correct?

Comment: I also getting warning at this part  `` return fetch(url, method: 'GET').then(response => response.json())
            }``

Comment: Tried to refactor my own code to work with it - doesn't work at all, ufortuantley.

Comment: @WizardRew
what kind of warning?